# Pull AD users from new AD server Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

we finally made an upgrade. Originally, we had 1 server running NAS, DNS, AD and DHCP. We just got another server strictly for AD, DNS and DHCP. I have everything installed and ready to go.

The question I have is when I disable these services on the old server and have the old server join the new server's domain, how do I pull in the AD users/groups to give permissions on the Network Share?

I  Googled for a bit, but I don't really know what this is called (I'm a developer but my boss just assumed that because I program, I also do networking and IT. Sorry if this is a dumb question.). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Both servers are running Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Does this imply you've created a new forest/domain on the new, dedicated, DC? It might have been simpler to join the new server to the old DC's domain and then promote the new server to a DC. You could then demote the old DC (after moving NAS to where ever). You may also want to consider that a single DC not ideal, nor is running DHCP on the DC.

Comment: I agree with jscott. Another question, just to clarify, did your old server act as the NAS?  Or do you have a dedicated NAS box, e.g., like a Netgear ReadyNAS, that is sharing your files?

Comment: Yeah, I created a new domain. I saw that option to promote and demote, I just didn't want to play with it while everyone was using it lol. I really wanted to get a better server license so i could create separate hyper-v instances, each running their own service so when I get a budget for more hardware, I can easily add more DC and DNS servers. Unfortunately, I only had a few bucks to work with.

Comment: @Art.Vandelay05 the old server(technically the current server because that's what everyone's using until I tinker with it tonight) is also the NAS and will remain the NAS. I just want to know how to make it when people join the new server (10.1.10.4) and then they connect to the NAS to open their files (10.1.10.3), how will all of their Usernames and Passwords sync up from the new server?

Comment: "I just want to know how to make it when people join the new server (10.1.10.4) and then they connect to the NAS to open their files (10.1.10.3), how will all of their Usernames and Passwords sync up from the new server?" - the way to do that would have been to "play with" (Or better still, read the documentation and do it properly) the option to join the current domain rather than create a new forest. You've done almost exactly the most wrong thing you could do in order to reasonably achieve the result you wanted.

Comment: @RobM lol. I mean, I could still do it this way. I'm not married to the option I chose. So the old server would still be a domain controller in the "forest" and would sync with the new server. Permissions on the network share wouldn't have to be adjusted at all if that's the case.

Comment: Ah, ok.  If it was a dedicated NAS box I might could have helped you do close to what you want with a robocopy command, but it won't work now.  You won't be able to get the ACLs (AD usernames and passwords permissions on the file shares) you need for your file shares since you created a new AD forest so you won't be able to sync their usernames and passwords.  Even if you use the same name and password their AD accounts are different from your old forest and so won't work on your file server.

Comment: @Art.Vandelay05 yeah, so I'd have to reset all the permissions with like icacls.

Comment: I mean, technically you guys answered my question. I just need to keep the AD services installed on the old server just either need to reconfigure to be in the forest with the new server or have the new server join the current domain and promote it. Makes sense. One of you should answer this so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it sounds like your old server is still running the "old" AD Forest.  That's good.  Ideally, you would want to reinstall Windows Server 2012 R2 on your new server and then join it to your domain and promote it to a domain controller.  However, if you can't reinstall Windows, you can demote the new server from being a domain controller, then join it to the domain.

I recommend following the steps in this link to remove AD DS and demote your new server. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574104.aspx

After demotion, you can join the new server to your current domain, install AD Domain Services, and promote it to a DC. 
https://www.petri.com/windows-server-2012-as-domain-controller

Your new server will now be a second DC in your current domain.

Comment: Awesome and thorough explanation. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank You!